# QuickbloxWebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

My project was working fine but after update the version `iOS 10` **`QuickbloxWebRTC/QuickbloxWebRTC.h` file not found** issue encountered, i have regenerate framework from quickblox and new framework build but still i get error.